# How to link of console.log refer to formatted js on Firefox devtool?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, firefox-developer-tools

Reading minified js is very difficult. so I am using pretty-print tool on developer tool on the browser.

In Chrome developer tools, when  js code have formatted, console.log link (this link indicate the points of console.log called, its link is there at the right side of console.log result) is refer to place in formatted source code.

However, In Firefox these links refer to minified source code even if the source code have already formatted.

Is there a way to change the reference of Firefox console.log link to indicate formatted source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality was recently added to Firefox; you can read [the implementing bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=952127) for details.

It is targeted at Firefox 58, so if you want this today, you'll have to run Nightly.

Note that this still does not work in all cases.  For example, if you have a generated source-mapped file, and then open one of the corresponding original sources, pretty-printing the original source will not update the locations.

Comment: I downloaded Nightly (Firefox 58a1) But this still does not work. Should I disable enable soucemap checkbox on settings of developer tool?

Comment: They have to be enabled for this to work at all.  If it's not working for you, maybe you're pretty-printing an original source or something like that?  Or maybe file a new bug.

Comment: opps I was under the impression that testing with Nightly, but I opened Developer Edition. I am using same theme and same menu setting on both browser. It works on Nightly.